# On suffienct condition on extending transpose of linear operator from dense subset to the closure.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose we want to find the transpose of a linear operator on $L^{p}[a,b]$ to $L^{p}[a,b]$. If we slove the following equation

$(Af,g)=(f,A^{*}g)$ for $g \in C[a,b]$ with the norm that makes its completion $L^{p}$. Is boundedness on $A$ sufficent so extend the adjont to the closure and establish that this is a suitable transpose on  $L^{q}[a,b]$.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you would like to ask. Does $A$ map $L^p$ to $L^p$? Anyway, if you have a bounded operator on a dense subspace, you can extend it by continuity to the whole space. And if $A$ is bounded, so is the adjoint $A^*$.

Comment: @gerw well it boils down to whether it suffice to have boundedness for $A$ on $L^{p}$. But if what you are saying is true then boundedness on $C[0,1]$ would suffice which donst look right since the operator could behave very badly on the closure unless we have boundedness on the closure I think.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are normed spaces, where $Y$ is complete, $S\subset X$ is a dense subspace, and $A \colon S \to Y$ a continuous (bounded) linear map, then $A$ has a unique continuous extension $\tilde{A}\colon X \to Y$, and we have $\lVert \tilde{A}\rVert = \lVert A\rVert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer But do we always get boundedness of the extension on the closure from this?

Comment: For linear maps between normed spaces, continuity and boundedness coincide.

Comment: @DanielFischer right, well back to the question. We reason in the following way ; $A^{*}$ is the adjoint on dense subset and hence must be bounded there with same norm as $A$ and can therefore be extended to $L^{p}$? We cant just extend $A^{*}$ w.o justification since it might not be bounded on $C[a,b]$ and hence might not posses cts extension. My question is which was the simples justification. And I think this boundedness on $C[a,b]$ of $A$ might be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boundedness of the operator $A$ on $C[a,b]$ should be sufficent to deduce existance of the adjoint on whole of $L^{p}$.